# How to use Prettify with Pelican?

Tags: prettify, pelican

I would like to use [prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) instead of [Pelican](http://blog.getpelican.com/)'s default code highligher on a Pelican site.  I disabled the default code highlighting by specifying the `MD_EXTENSIONS` [setting](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.4.0/settings.html) manually in `pelicanconf.py` and not including the `codehilite` extension.  I've also successfully included `prettify` in the template.

**The missing bit:**

Prettify requires `<code>` or `<pre>` tags to have the attribute `class="prettyprint"`, as explained [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted).  How can I coerce Pelican to include this attribute by default?

Comment: For those curious, Pygments doesn't have *good* support for highlighting Mathematica code, while prettify [does](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting) (it is used on [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) and it's being maintained).  Most of the code I want to highlight is Mathematica code.  (I am aware of the existing Pygments Mathematica highlighter: it is not good enough.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to edit theme it self.

Comment: That will not solve "the missing bit", as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the following it is necessary to use version 2.6 (or later) of the Python-Markdown package.

In `pelicanconf.py`, add

```
MD_EXTENSIONS  = [
   'extra',
   'codehilite(linenums=False,css_class=prettyprint,guess_lang=False,use_pygments=False)'
]
```

The two key settings are `use_pygments=False`, which will cause code-highlight to simply output `<pre><code>...` blocks, and `css_class=prettyprint`, which adds the required class to `<pre>` tags.

Now modify the Pelican theme according to [prettify's setup instructions](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) and you're set!